# What is the stringy slimy stuff in Peace Tea?

Tags: tea

I bought a Sno-berry Peace Tea today that had a slimy stringy substance in it. I pulled it out of my mouth after unknowingly drinking it, and I put it into a napkin. Once the moisture was out of it, it was a strong, fibrous string...Any idea what this is??

Comment: Sounds like fungus. Where did you buy it, and do you have a date from the package?

Answer (score 2):

The [ingredients list](https://www.coca-colaproductfacts.com/en/products/peace-tea/sno-berry/23-oz/):

> TEA (WATER, TEA POWDER), CANE SUGAR, NATURAL FLAVORS, CITRIC ACID, PECTIN, SUCRALOSE

None of those should be slimy or stringy, and also wouldn't form a fibrous string even if it was sitting for a long time. It's almost impossible to know what did contaminate your drink. However, you can get in touch with the manufacturer about it!

Comment: Tough and fibrous would point to a piece of sugar cane.

Comment: A lump of pectin not properly dissolved could also be the cause